weighted random forest with train/test datasets
I have a dataset where the sample distribution does not match the population distribution, but I have weights that can be applied to address that issue. I have randomly partitioned the original dataset into training and testing datasets and am using ranger with the caseweights=myweight argument to create a weighted random forest regression model with the training data.  It seems like the test dataset should also be weighted when calculating the RMSE and MAE. I am doing the following with the test dataset:
# weight is a vector equal in length to the predicted and observed vectors
 mse <- mean(weight*(predicted - observed)^2)
 mae <- mean(weight*abs(predicted - observed))

Does this approach make sense?

Yes, weighted calculation of test-set MSEs and MAEs makes sense in the situation you describe. Typically we want to estimate how well our model should perform on unseen data, on average across the population. So if your test set isn't a simple random sample from the population, unweighted MSE will be biased for the true expected MSE; but if you have appropriate weights, then a weighted MSE should alleviate this problem.
See for instance Wieczorek, Guerin, & McMahon (2022), "K-fold cross-validation for complex sample surveys," Stat: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/sta4.454
That said, make sure the weights you are using are sampling weights (or similar, perhaps with adjustments for nonresponse and so on), not other kinds of weights.
